# How do i set multiple http header using sessionManager (AFNetworking)

Tags: objective-c, ios9, afnetworking-3

I have searched through various stackoverflow  questions and I got answer but using `NSMutableURLRequest` as there is one method `- (void)addValue:(NSString *)value forHTTPHeaderField:(NSString *)field;` which can be called over `requestObject` only.
How do I add value using `_sessionManager.requestSerializer` ?Or any work around. Here is the code which I am using for session configuration.

```
- (void)configureSesionManager {
_sessionManager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
_sessionManager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

_sessionManager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
_sessionManager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];
_sessionManager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = 360;
if ([GSCommonUtil isUserLoggedIn]) {
    authenticationHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",[GSCommonUtil retriveValueFromUserDefaults:kNSUserAuthenticationToken]];
    [_sessionManager.requestSerializer setValue:authenticationHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
} 
    [_sessionManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"text/plain" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [_sessionManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
// I have to add one more HTTPHeader for @"Accept". How could I achieve it.
    NSLog(@"Done with Session Manager Configuration!");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Accept` header takes a [comma separated list](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#z3), so something like this should work:

`[_sessionManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json, application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];`

Obviously replace `application/xml` with whatever you need.